# SQL query, only select if column is not null else don't select

Tags: mysql, sql, null

This is what i am trying to do

```
 SELECT `a`, `b`, `c` FROM `tbl` WHERE `a` IS NOT NULL OR `b` IS NOT NULL OR `c` IS NOT NULL WHERE id = ?
```

If a and c are null and b isn't I still receive this result set\

```
 a      b     c 
____   ____   ____   

NULL  value   NULL
```

But i only want that it returns this

```
   b
  ____

  value
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just want the first non null value of the 3? or are you looking to display 2 columns if 2 values are not null?

Comment: I want to receive all non null columns else dont return them :) So yes if 2 columns are not null display those 2.

Comment: you need a prepare statement to select the columns dynamically

Comment: And how do i do that? Sorry i don't have very much experience with sql can you give me a example :p

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense without further details. Suppose you have two rows: (null, value, null), (value, null,null). What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Maybe you want something like `SELECT CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN a ELSE '' `

Comment: I suspect you're going to have to handle this on the front-end. You're going to get back from the database each column in the select clause.

Comment: @JimGarrison I only want to select all the not null values else don't display them. And i also suspected that but you never know..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get a row with two columns when there are two non-null columns, and 1 if there's only one, you have to dynamically create your query.

If you want to always have 1 column where each row contains a non-null value, you can do it with a union.

```
SELECT a FROM tbl WHERE a IS NOT NULL AND id = ?
UNION
SELECT b FROM tbl WHERE b IS NOT NULL AND id = ?
UNION
SELECT c FROM tbl WHERE c IS NOT NULL AND id = ?
```

If you want to able to know which from which columns the values come, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 'col a' AS ColName, a FROM tbl WHERE a IS NOT NULL AND id = ?
UNION
SELECT 'col b', b FROM tbl WHERE b IS NOT NULL AND id = ?
UNION
SELECT 'col c', c FROM tbl WHERE c IS NOT NULL AND id = ?
```

Note: union also removes duplicate results. If you want to keep duplicates, use `UNION ALL`.