# Only reads columns with values + print date from same column (complicated)

Tags: sql, pivot, case

Here is something for your brains to bite on :D

Im not able to solve this out by myself. My table has the same princip as the fiddle example but col1-col32 instead of only col1-col5 like in the example.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f6da

Goal is to get the output:

```
Apples, 20120104, 9.73
Berries, 20120101, 4.00
Berries, 20120103, 3.50
Bananas, 20120101,2.30
Kiwi, 20120103, 5.55
```

I know that the table has bad columns names and that the data is badly stored. Im not searching for help how to change the table, i have to work with the data as it is.

Thanks for your help

Comment: But why do you store data like that? And that's bad column names...

Comment: Well it's not me who stores data like this,i just have to accept the situation.

Comment: a better way to build this schema would have been to create two tables. (1) containing names and Id and (2) containing id, date, value and id for parent.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24472207/2931427

Comment: You can only do this by constructing you query dynamically for each record separately.

Answer (score 2):

It is not so complicated as it seems:

```
;with cte as(
Select * from example
unpivot(c for d in([col2],[col3],[col4],[col5]))u
)
select c2.col1, c2.c, c1.c from cte c1
Join cte c2 on c1.d = c2.d
where c1.col1 = 'datum' and c2.col1 <> 'datum' and c2.c <> '0.00'
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f6da/22

Comment: Thanks almost there but im missing a column with the date

Comment: This is good. I would consider pulling the column names using dynamic sql though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f6da/29

Comment: @user2210516, answer was edited already with date column before you posted