# MySQL select rows and ignore row if column is blank

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

Using Dreamweaver CS5 / MySQL

I'm trying to set up a query that will display rows of data but only if a specific column has data in it. If the Charname column is blank I don't want that row to be displayed.

Currently the query works, but it also displays the rows when the Charname column is empty. I'm struggling to set up and have failed at every turn to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
mysql_select_db($database_login_form, $login_form);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $login_form) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);


<?php do { ?>
<li><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Charname']; ?></a></li>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp? Don't you just need to append to the query`"SELECT * FROM users"` to make it contain a `WHERE column_name IS NOT NULL` clause?

Comment: `$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE charname != '' AND charname IS NOT NULL";` This is what you're looking for, but I would seriously look into learning basic SQL, as this is really one of the most basic lessons.

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE something != "";

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471704/sql-query-only-select-if-column-is-not-null-else-dont-select

check this for better solution if you want to check all columns

Comment: im sorry, but why you use `do while` ? `do while` will be executed at least once, even though data taken from the database is empty, how if you try using `while` only, thanks :)

Comment: Adding the WHERE clause isn't changing what is being displayed at all. It still displays the blank rows regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE()` to treat blank (empty string) and `NULL` as the same thing:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE COALESCE(Charname, '') != ''
```

You never told us what "empty" actually means, but a good guess would be empty string or `NULL`.

Comment: This resolved my issue, thank you so, so much. I've been at this for hours trying different methods, when the normal where / null statement didn't work is where I got stuck. THANK YOU AGAIN. <3

Answer (score 4):

update your query like this

```
SELECT * FROM users where Charname IS NOT NULL or Charname != '';
```

you can also use `COALESCE()` for check null

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE COALESCE(Charname, '') != '';
```

for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

and you can aslo check in your php end

suppose like this

```
$Charname = $row_Recordset1['Charname'];
if($Charname == '' || $Charname === null || is_null($Charname)){
   continue;
}
```

Comment: Adding the Where / Null Statement doesn't change the issue. It still displays the row even if the Charname column is blank.

Comment: you are welcome, normally first answer will work but if empty string in this case second answer and you can also check using php